# Count how many decimal places in a decimal number in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a decimal number:

```
num=0.000001
```

I want to get the decimal places count, using bash shell

Required output:

```
decimalPointsCount=$(code to get decimal places length of $num variable)
```

Any awk,sed,perl..etc suggestions would be appreciated,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell alone can do that:

```
num=0.000001
decimals=${num#*.}              #Removes the integer part and the dot (=000001)
decimalPointsCount=${#decimals} #Counts the length of resulting string (=6)
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice words as always!, @RavinderSingh13